# HTML hyperlink underline on mouseover

Tags: html, hyperlink

This is for a class project I have finished, but we can get bonus points for doing extras. I removed the underline in my hyperlink, and I was wondering if there was a way to put the underine back on a mouseover? I'm also not allowed to use CSS or anything other than HTML. I don't know if it is possible, but here is what I have:

```
    <a href="http://www.tolkien.co.uk/index.html" style="text-decoration:none">J.R.R. Tolkien
```

Comment: `text-decoration:none` **is** CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with. What I will say though is that you are technically using CSS with the `style`, `onmouseover`, and `onmouseout` events, it is just doing so without the need of a CSS file because the `style` event is just making html understand it itself. The `style` event is then on the other two events, giving them the power to use CSS with only the html file.

```html
<a href="http://www.tolkien.co.uk/index.html" style="text-decoration:none" onmouseover="style='text-decoration:underline'" onmouseout="style='text-decoration:none'">J.R.R. Tolkien</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this without Css,  if you want to try it's : 

 `a:hover{ text-decoration: underline;}`

Answer (score 0):

HTML has no mechanism to remove the underline from a link containing text.

The `text-decoration: none` syntax you are using is CSS. The `style` attribute takes the body of a CSS rule-set as its value.

The only ways to apply CSS dynamically based on if the mouse is pointing to something are with a separate stylesheet (where you can use selectors, including rulesets) or with JavaScript (where you can modify the CSS based on events).